# Updating Grid View from List Box

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, webforms

I have a list box like this,

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="175px" Width="213px">
            <asp:ListItem Value="all">All</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="programmer">Computer Programmer</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="itss">Information Technologies Support Services</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="analyst">Systems Analyst</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
```

and a Grid View like this,

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="program" HeaderText="Program" 
                    SortExpression="program" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile.xml" 
            TransformFile="~/XSLTFile.xslt"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

Grid View is getting values from a XML & XSLT file. What I want to do is, when user selects suppose Computer Programmer from list box, the grid view should get updated with the results  of only those have this program. How can I do this? Do I have to bind the xml with List Box?

Comment: did you google it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6c0928s.aspx

Comment: filtering never came to my mind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is filter your `DataSource` of your `GridView` based on what was selected in the `ListBox`.

When `ListBox1`'s selected index changes, fire off the event and with the `AutoPostBack` property and Filter the `XMLDataSource` depending on what the value selected was.

```
Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim selected As String = ListBox1.SelectedValue
    FilterDataSource(selected)
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Depending on the selected value passed in, filter the XMLDataSource
''' by the selected value
''' </summary>
''' <param name="selected">The value of the selected item in ListBox1</param>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub FilterDataSource(ByVal selected As String)
    ' Do whatever logic applies that will filter the XMLDataSource
    Select Case selected

        Case "all"

        Case "progammer"

        Case "itss"

        Case "analyst"

    End Select
End Sub
```